# Regex finding all substrings between markers keeps extra characters

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm really confused because I don't think those are special characters. In either case I tried prepending them with a backslash.
But I have a big text file that's basically html code. And i want to extract text between some tags.
I cropped a piece below:

```
b282yb keod5gw0 nxhoafnm aigsh9s9 d3f4x2em iv3no6db jq4qci2q a3bd9o3v lrazzd5p
 bwm1u5wc" dir="auto"><span class="a8c37x1j ni8dbmo4 stjgntxs l9j0dhe7 ltmttdrg
 g0qnabr5">Text #1</span></a></div><div class="aahdfvyu"></span></span></div>
</div><div class="n00jemau55g9w c8b282yb keod5gw0 nxhoafnm aigsh9s9 d3f4x2em 
mdeji52x a5q79mjw g1cxx5fr lrazzd5p oo9gr5id" dir="auto">Text #2</span></a></div>
<div class="aahdfvyu"><span class="d2edcug0 hpfvmrgz qv66sw1b c1e
```

i want it to return `['Text #1', 'Text #2']`

i tried doing

`result = re.findall(r'>(.*?)</span></a></div><div class="aahdfvyu">', f)`

but it comes back with

`['<span class="a8c37x1j ni8dbmo4 stjgntxs l9j0dhe7 ltmttdrg g0qnabr5">Text #1', '</span></div></div><div class="n00jemau55g9w c8b282yb keod5gw0 nxhoafnm aigsh9s9 d3f4x2em mdeji52x a5q79mjw g1cxx5fr lrazzd5p oo9gr5id" dir="auto">Text #2']`

so it doesn't remove everything before the string. Why?

Comment: Don't you want to use special libraries for html parsing? `BeautifulSoup` will work with much more readable code. You can write a proper regex (current doesn't work, because you select the first matching closing angle brace (`>`), then everything until remaining part of pattern is met). The following regex will work (for this input, assuming that angle braces are not allowed in text): `re.findall(r'>([^<>]*?)</span></a></div><div class="aahdfvyu">', f)`, because you don't allow any tags to be inside group. It's easy to construct counterexamples for almost any regex solution of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text="""b282yb keod5gw0 nxhoafnm aigsh9s9 d3f4x2em iv3no6db jq4qci2q a3bd9o3v
lrazzd5pbwm1u5wc" dir="auto"><span class="a8c37x1j ni8dbmo4 stjgntxs l9j0dhe7
ltmttdrgg0qnabr5">Text #1</span></a></div><div class="aahdfvyu"></span></span></div>
</div><div class="n00jemau55g9w c8b282yb keod5gw0 nxhoafnm aigsh9s9 d3f4x2emmdeji52x a5q79mjw g1cxx5fr lrazzd5p oo9gr5id" dir="auto">Text #2</span></a></div><div class="aahdfvyu"><span class="d2edcug0 hpfvmrgz qv66sw1b c1e"""

re.findall(r'>([^<]+)</span></a></div><div class="aahdfvyu">',text)
```

result

```
['Text #1', 'Text #2']
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nhey62/1)